# iOS Asymmetric encryption stuff

Tags: ios, encryption

I want to generate a key pair once and save it to a file. In my own app, I want to encrypt data with it's private key. In the app I will distribute, I want that data to be verified as mine with the public key.

I found APIS like SecKeyGeneratePair and Encrypt/Decrypt but I am not sure how to export the key to a file, so I redistribute the public key with my public app, and how to create a SecKeyRef from imported data of the public or the private key.

I found this (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m.html) but I am not sure if it helps, I didn't find any exporting/importing in that sample.

Comment: You probably don't want encryption, but rather signatures.

Comment: It's the same concept, the main problem is how to store and retrieve the keys from/to SecKeyRef.